# Gmaps4rails not displaying markers with latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I have seen previous questions regarding this issue but they are not recent have not been answered (please correct me if I am wrong)...

Anyways here is the issue I have been having with Gmaps4rails gem. The latitude and longitude are recorded (using geocoder gem) but they will not display on the gmaps4rails map. The map displays fine on the show page but there are no markers.

**provider.rb - model**

[image]

**show.html.haml**
[image]

**providers_controller.rb - controller**
[image]

**latitude and longitude recorded in active admin**
[image]

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I feel stupid. Copied and pasted my `index` action code into the `show` action and everything worked perfectly

Copied and pasted this into the `show` action.

```
@providers = Provider.all
@markers = ...
```